# Excel VBA TreeView linking to ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, treeview

I have a userform in which I have a TreeView and a ComboBox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With TreeView1.Nodes
.Add , , "A", "Item1"
    .Add "A", tvwChild, , "SubItem1"

.Add , , "B", "Item2"
    .Add "B", tvwChild, , "SubItem2"
End With 

With ComboBox1
.AddItem "Case1"
.AddItem "Case2"
.AddItem "Case3"
.AddItem "Case4"
End With 

End Sub
```

My goal now is that when I select a parent node in the TreeView, that only certain items from the ComboBox are displayed to me. For example: I select Item2 and in the ComboBox Case 1 and Case 3 are only shown to me. What I tried was to make a If loop but it didn't work out.

How can I actually do this and is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TreeView1_NodeClick` event returns the `Node` that was clicked.  Use the `Node.Text` value to determine which items are added to the `ComboBox`.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeClick(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    With ComboBox1
        .Clear
        Select Case Node.Text
            Case "A"
                .AddItem "Case1"
                .AddItem "Case3"
            Case "B"
                .AddItem "Case2"
                .AddItem "Case4"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

### Addendum

OP pointed out that he needed to use the `Node.Key` property for his use case.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeClick(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    With ComboBox1
        .Clear
        Select Case Node.Key
            Case "A"
                .AddItem "Case1"
                .AddItem "Case3"
            Case "B"
                .AddItem "Case2"
                .AddItem "Case4"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering, I've tried this out, but it still doesn't work. Whenever I click now on one Node there are no elements in the combobox

Comment: I found the reason, it is because of node.text, it should be replaced by node.key since we use the key as reference

Comment: Do you know if it is possible when I select the parent node and later all child nodes that it still shows me. Because now, when i click on subitem1 it doesnt show me the case 1 and 3 again

Comment: @RedR4nger you can iterate through the `Node.Children`.  We can also transverse up the tree using `Node.Parent`.  You may want to tag some of the `Nodes` using  the `Node.Tag` property.